# Web Services Rest en Genexus Evo3

Tags: rest

Tengo una KB en Evo3 con varios dataViews asociados a varios DataStores (MySQL y Oracle) y otros tantos procedures en donde consulto datos de esos dataViews y expongo los procedures como Web Services Rest.

En otra KB estoy consumiendo (correctamente) esos WS. El problema es que pasado cierto tiempo, mi servidor (Tomcat 7) cae por java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space. La aplicacion cliente tiene mucha concurrencia (pedidos de clientes) y en la pantalla de seleccion de productos para pedidos tengo una grilla y por cada producto estoy llamando a un WS para recuperar el stock del producto. Puede ser este un motivo?, ya que por cada producto estoy llamando al WS.

En ambiente de pruebas, con baja concurrencia, no tengo problemas.

Gracias